# Notating an arbitrarily long series of series

Tags: summation, notation

Is there a better notation for the following sum?

\begin{equation}
y = \sum\limits_{x_1}^{S_{x_0}} \sum\limits_{x_2}^{S_{x_1}} \dots \sum\limits_{x_{n}}^{S_{x_{n-1}}} f(x_n)
\end{equation}

The fact that each inner sum depends on the next outer-most sum makes me skeptical that it's possible to reorder the sums in any way. Is there some already well-accepted notation for this other than using dots to signal an extended sum of sums?

Comment: Can you explain what the notation means? Usually a sum has three parts; a dummy variable, a initial number, and a final number. However, your sums only have two parts.

Comment: Interpreting the product symbol as an operator, one could write $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{x_k}^{S_{x_{k-1}}}\right)f(\vec x) $$

Comment: That's a bit precarious, I feel. What does it mean to multiply two summation operators when their index set is dependent on the other? If it simply means to compose them as a larger sum, why are we not using composition? Note that the original definition of $y$ I provided contains only sums, no products or factors (outside of $f(x_n)$).